# changes made to source code not showing in the application - how to clear tomcat cache completely

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have a maven project which I am deploying in tomcat by creating a war file and placing it in the `webapps` directory of `tomcat`, and running it from `localhost/manager`. The application starts and works no problem. Now, I need to make some modifications in the source code, and the problem is the changes I am making in the source code are not taking effect in the application. Here is what I've tried:

1. Clear the browser cache
2. Undeploy the project from `localhost/manager`
3. Delete the project folder from `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\work\myProject`
4. Recreate the war file by running the command `mvn clean package -Pdev`
5. Place the new war file in the `webapps` directory of `tomcat`
6. Start the project and open it

After all these steps the application is behaving excatly how it was before, I even deleted some major methods from the source code which are responsible for loading the project, but still no change. Where is the project cached and how can I see the changes I am making?

Comment: Be sure to remove the folder with the same name as your `.war` file in Tomcat's `webapps` folder. It contains the extracted contents of your war file and might not be updated correctly when deploying a new war file of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you as steps for deploying on tomcat:

1. Stop tomcat application or service
2. Go to your `webapp` folder (the one related to your project), and remove all files from it (both .war and extracted files)
3. Delete the `work` folder from tomcat root path
4. Copy your `.war` file to your webapp folder
5. Restart Tomcat

A tip: you can easly autodeploy your app with Maven by using a plugin , you can find all info [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html). With this you can easly run `tomcat7:redeploy` , he will take care of the dirt and the deploy operations :)

Comment: Thank you for the input @Leviand. I did restart tomcat as well. I cannot delete the whole work folder as it contains other projects belong to other developers, but deleting my own project from that folder should be enough no?

Comment: Yes, Just delete that one ;)

Comment: I did delete one tho as mentioned in the question, but still tomcat using the same old source code which I don't understand how. Is it cached somewhere else other than work directory?